# ASP.NET roles (old style) not "persisting"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, roleprovider

So, I'm using "old style" ASP.NET roles and auth.  I have a custom log in page which redirects based on roles upon login.  Works fine... But when I get to the destination page where I need to recheck, it fails.  Same user, same role, etc.
I've tried both "User.IsInRole" and "Roles.IsUserInRole " with the same result.  I've also tried specifically setting cache roles in cookie in my config, nothing works.

As always, I'm deeply indebted for any suggestions!

Comment: Please post your "recheck" code.

Comment: @mxmissile the most recent is:
  if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("/login.aspx");
            }

Just to check it, and it fails regardless of what I've tried

Comment: Are you on a web farm, or single server?  Web farms will need to have the same machine key in order to decrypt the auth cookie.

Comment: @MarkW Just testing so far on my local machine

Comment: Are you using a custom membership and/or role provider?

Comment: @MarkW using the asp,net providers, just the login page is "custom"

Comment: OK... maybe I've forgotten how this works (very possible), but this is what I got that functions "properly":

 if (Membership.ValidateUser(nameTest, passwordLogIn.Text))
              {
                  FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(nameTest,       passwordLogIn.Text);
             
                  FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(nameTest, rememberMe.Checked);
              
                }

etc... not what I recall doing in the past but it seems to do the job.

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 "edit" the question and add relevant code there. Dont add code to the comments.

Comment: @mxmissile thanks, still learning my way around here